# regular expression match using python for string with multiple spaces and special character

Tags: python, regex

match() in following string,

```
string = "(branch=MAIN).  See the error log at /home/aswamy/run/test_upgrade/2.0-285979.customer_deployment.22499/test.log.2\n"
m = re.match("See the error",string)
print m  ==> (Here m always shows None)
```

But if I use the same string without any spaces between (branch=MAIN), then match happens as below,

```
string = "See the error log at /home/kperiyaswamy/runmass/mass_test_upgrade/7.2.0-285979.customer_deployment.22499/infoblox.log.2\n"
m = re.match("See the error",string)
print m ===> (works proper <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fe813825030>)
```

So if there is a multiple white spaces pattern match doesn't work. Please let me know how to solve above issue

Comment: `m = re.search("See the error",string)`

Comment: change it to

    `m = re.match(".*See the error",string)`

That way you specify that the string can start with every character and when there is a match and shows it.

Answer (score 1):

Its not about the `whitespaces`.`match` always starts to match from the beginning of the string.In 2nd case the string is at the start.So you get the match.In first case it isnt so you dont get a match.Use `findall` if you want to get a match in any case.